# Latitude and longitude of Eugene Shoemaker's final resting place?

Tags: observational-astronomy, history

Eugene Shoemaker was an esteemed and celebrated astronomer and planetary geologist. Is it possible to localize their final resting place with a latitude, longitude and feature name?

Comment: I've linked to this question [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/46324/12102), hopefully it can be answered soon!

Comment: Pretty certain they crashed the Lunar Prospector into the Shoemaker Crater. Is that accurate enough?

Comment: @RoryAlsop you're welcome to post that as an answer with the lat/lon of the crater's center, but there might be more detailed information available on Prospector's final trajectory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A small portion of Eugene Shoemaker's ashes were placed on the Lunar Prospector mission. After completion of the mission's primary objectives:

> Lunar Prospector was deliberately impacted onto the shadowed Shoemaker crater on the lunar surface at 09:52:02 UT July 31, 1999.
> [NASA Mission Description](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/missions/lunar-prospector/in-depth/)

No coordinates are given in that source, however, the Google Earth rendering of the Moon has a placemark for the crash site.  No coordinates are listed.
A [source](https://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/1999/ast21jul99_1/) from before the impact occurred lists the planned crash site as 87.70 S 42.0 E, which is very close to the placemark, and gives an estimated crash time within a minute of the actual event.

Thus, the likely resting place of that portion of Shoemaker's ashes may be gives as: 87.70S 42.0E, Shoemaker Crater.

Note: The idea of crashing into the crater was put forth by the University of Texas at Austin, and they had a small site about the crash.  I was able to find a snapshot from the period that has working links on the Internet Archive [here](https://web.archive.org/web/19990819014446/http://www.ae.utexas.edu/%7Ecfpl/lunar/).
There was also an entire site devoted to the amateur astronomy aspect of the crash, also on the Internet Archive: [lunarimpact.com](https://web.archive.org/web/19991012230902/http://lunarimpact.com/).
[Information](https://web.archive.org/web/19991023075849/http://www.ae.utexas.edu/%7Ecfpl/lunar/observations.html) from these sites indicates that the reason the crash time was different was due to a stronger-than-expected deorbit burn, and thus the actual crash site might be closer to 87.7S, 42.1E, which is exactly where the Google Earth marker is. The [last mission report](https://web.archive.org/web/20000511140352/http://lunar.arc.nasa.gov/status/index.html), however, lists it as 87.7S 42E.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy answer! Following your 2nd link I found [this](https://cfpl.ae.utexas.edu/the-1999-impact-of-lunar-prospector-into-the-lunar-south-pole) and [this](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1029/1999GL900384) (open access)

Comment: Excellent!  I was actually working through the internet archive, trying to get to the right snapshot.  I'll add my links into the answer as well.